# Django - populate table on startup with known values

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Dog Model that have a "dog_type" field. i want the dog_type to be chosen from a list of pre-defined dog types, i DO NOT want to use a textfield with choices but a ForeignKey to a "DogType" Model. How could I populate the DogType Model with types on server startup? is this a good practice or a hack?
thanks.
code:

```
class Dog(Model):
      name = CharField(...)
      dog_type = ForeignKey(DogType)

class DogType(Model):
      type_name = CharField(...)
      type_max_hight = IntegerField(...)
      etc....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably want to write a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) that will add your choices in database.
Advantages of using this approach is that the data will be loaded in all your databases (production, dev, etc.)

(If you're not using migrations yet, you should consider it, it's a clean and well-supported way to manage your database)

In your django project, just run `python manage.py shell makemigrations myapp --empty`. This will create an empty migration file under `myapp/migrations`.

You can then edit it:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations

DEFAULT_DOG_TYPES = (
    ('Labrador', 90),
    ('Berger Allemand', 66),
    ('Chihuaha', -2),
)

def add_dog_types(apps, schema_editor):
    DogType = apps.get_model('myapp', 'DogType')

    for name, max_height in DEFAULT_DOG_TYPES:
        dog_type = DogType(name=name, max_height=max_height)
        dog_type.save()

def remove_dog_types(apps, schema_editor):
    # This is used to migrate backward
    # You can remove your dog types, or just pass
    # pass

    for name, max_height in DEFAULT_DOG_TYPES:
        dog_type = DogType.objects.get(name=name, max_height=max_height)
        dog_type.delete()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        # if you're already using migrations, this line will be different
        ('myapp', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(add_dog_types, remove_dog_types),
    ]
```

After that, all you need to do is to run `python manage.py syncdb`.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, a few comments:
1.this code yield a "CircularDependancyError", I think the dependency needs to be commented out.
2.for some reason django can't find my "myapp"...do i need to register it somewhere for this to worl?

Comment: The dependency was provided as an exemple. Same thing for myapp : you should use the real name of your app. I really insist on studying the whole migration stuff before using it, it will save you a lot of time and headaches ;)

Comment: I shall. for now i'm using fixtures, but for sure later will move for migration. thanks :)

Comment: Be careful, fixtures are on depreciation path and [will be removed in django 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.8/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-1-9)

Comment: I am aware of that, this is why our face is to migration. fixtures are just a workaround. thanks :))

Answer (score 0):

not so far after, i found [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/initial-data/) it's called "fixtures"...
basically what you need to do is to place a "fixture" file in a format of your choice (JSON\YAML...) "myapp/fixtures/" for example, a JSON file would look like this:

```
[
  {
    "model": "myapp.person",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "first_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Lennon"
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "myapp.person",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
      "first_name": "Paul",
      "last_name": "McCartney"
    }
  }
]
```

then simply run from the command line:

```
python manage.py loaddata <filename> # file with no path!
```

Comment: Also, linked answers promote spams and users would have to leave SO to find the answer, which is inconvenient. Please keep in mind that linked answers will get voted for deletion.